# Looking for JNA Library for Xamarin Android or Xamarin Form Project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, jna

one of my xamarin android / xamarin forms project has the dependency

JNA (https://github.com/java-native-access/jna)

I downloaded the jar/aar file and tried converting it to dll so that I can use it in my project but I failed doing so because the JAR file is obfuscated and was giving lot of error while creating a binding library

So my question is, is there any such prebuild library created for the same or nuget available that I can use ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can add the .jar file to your project.

**Here are the steps below:**

1. Create a new Java Bindings Library project.
2. Add the .JAR file to the project.
3. Set the appropriate build action for the .JAR file.
4. Choose a target framework that the .JAR supports.
5. Build the Bindings Library.

For more information, you can refer to the [Binding a .JAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar). This can help you.

Comment: @Gaungyu Bai I know how to make binding library but for JNA aar I am getting lot of issue for creating binding library so I was finding if there is already such package available

Comment: The JNA library belongs to the third party. I am afraid that they may not have the nuget package version.